# Difference between MSbuild command line and visual studio on code analysis

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a Jenkins server where I build and test my code. When I test code analysis with MSBuild on Jenkins server (by command line) I have 87 warnings. And if I test on visual studio, I have 572 warnings.
Which is a huge difference !
After investigation, many of missing warnings are warnings about syntax as [CA1704](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1704-identifiers-should-be-spelled-correctly?view=vs-2017) or [CA2204](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2204-literals-should-be-spelled-correctly?view=vs-2017).
I have a ruleset in my solution, and I give the solution path to MSbuild (so it should use this ruleset too, am I right?). So what is missing ? or What I'm doing wrong ?

For information, I use visual studio 2017.

Comment: What is your build command line when you build on Jenkins server? Which parameters you passed when you use command line?

Comment: The exact command is: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true C:\path\mySolution.sln", I will try @ApoorvaRaju command

Comment: You should have to use the CodeAnalysisRuleSet property in you command line: `msbuild solution.sln /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true;CodeAnalysisRuleSet=xxxxx.ruleset`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Executing through MSBuild Command Line we should enable Code Analysis using following command:
 /p:RunCodeAnalysis:true; and also you should specify the ruleset as CodeAnalysisRuleSet="path to the file"

In VS the codeanalysis could have been enabled in Solution property-->Code Analysis

Comment: I have done RunCodeAnalysis:true, but I will try CodeAnalysisRuleSet command

Comment: It's working, I though MSBuild will use the correct ruleset because I give the solution path to it, but it doesn't.